# Injecting Indexed Functor into Functor Coproduct

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, free-monad

I'm trying to work with an indexed free monad (Oleg Kiselyov has [an intro](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/ParamEff1.hs)). I also want that free monad to be built from a from a coproduct of functors a la [Data Types a la carte](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~W.Swierstra/Publications/DataTypesALaCarte.pdf). However, I'm having trouble getting the coproduct injection type class to work out. Here's what I have so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module Example where

import Control.Monad.Indexed
import Data.Kind
import Data.TASequence.FastCatQueue
import Prelude hiding ((>>), (>>=))

-- * Indexed free machinery

-- For use with `RebindableSyntax`
(>>=)
  :: (IxMonad m)
  => m s1 s2 a -> (a -> m s2 s3 b) -> m s1 s3 b
(>>=) = (>>>=)
(>>)
  :: (IxApplicative m)
  => m s1 s2 a -> m s2 s3 b -> m s1 s3 b
f >> g = imap (const id) f `iap` g

type family Fst x where
  Fst '(a, b) = a
type family Snd x where
  Snd '(a, b) = b

newtype IKleisliTupled m ia ob = IKleisliTupled
  { runIKleisliTupled :: Snd ia -> m (Fst ia) (Fst ob) (Snd ob)
  }

data Free f s1 s2 a where
  Pure :: a -> Free f s s a
  Impure ::
    f s1 s2 a ->
      FastTCQueue (IKleisliTupled (Free f)) '(s2, a) '(s3, b) ->
        Free f s1 s3 b

instance IxFunctor (Free f) where
  imap f (Pure a) = Pure $ f a
  imap f (Impure a g) = Impure a (g |> IKleisliTupled (Pure . f))
instance IxPointed (Free f) where
  ireturn = Pure
instance IxApplicative (Free f) where
  iap (Pure f) (Pure a) = ireturn $ f a
  iap (Pure f) (Impure a g) = Impure a (g |> IKleisliTupled (Pure . f))
  iap (Impure a f) m = Impure a (f |> IKleisliTupled (`imap` m))
instance IxMonad (Free f) where
  ibind f (Pure a) = f a
  ibind f (Impure a g) = Impure a (g |> IKleisliTupled f)

-- * Example application

data FileStatus
  = FileOpen
  | FileClosed
data File i o a where
  Open :: FilePath -> File 'FileClosed 'FileOpen ()
  Close :: File 'FileOpen 'FileClosed ()
  Read :: File 'FileOpen 'FileOpen String
  Write :: String -> File 'FileOpen 'FileOpen ()

data MayFoo
  = YesFoo
  | NoFoo
data Foo i o a where
  Foo :: Foo 'NoFoo 'YesFoo ()

data MayBar
  = YesBar
  | NoBar
data Bar i o a where
  Bar :: Bar 'YesBar 'NoBar ()

-- * Coproduct of indexed functors

infixr 5 `SumP`
data SumP f1 f2 t1 t2 x where
  LP :: f1 sl1 sl2 x -> SumP f1 f2 '(sl1, sr) '(sl2, sr) x
  RP :: f2 sr1 sr2 x -> SumP f1 f2 '(sl, sr1) '(sl, sr2) x

-- * Attempt 1

class Inject l b where
  inj :: forall a. l a -> b a

instance Inject (f i o) (f i o) where
  inj = id

instance Inject (fl il ol) (SumP fl fr '(il, s) '(ol, s)) where
  inj = LP

instance (Inject (f i' o') (fr is os)) =>
         Inject (f i' o') (SumP fl fr '(s, is) '(s, os)) where
  inj = RP . inj

send
  :: Inject (t i o) (f is os)
  => t i o b -> Free f is os b
send t = Impure (inj t) (tsingleton (IKleisliTupled Pure))

-- Could not deduce `(Inject (Bar 'YesBar 'NoBar) f s30 s40)`
prog
  :: (Inject (File 'FileClosed 'FileOpen) (f s1 s2)
     ,Inject (Foo 'NoFoo 'YesFoo) (f s2 s3)
     ,Inject (Bar 'YesBar 'NoBar) (f s3 s4)
     ,Inject (File 'FileOpen 'FileClosed) (f s4 s5))
  => Free f s1 s5 ()
prog = do
  send (Open "/tmp/foo.txt")
  x <- send Read
  send Foo
  send (Write x)
  send Bar
  send Close

-- * Attempt 2

bsend :: (t i o b -> g is os b) -> t i o b -> Free g is os b
bsend f t = Impure (f t) (tsingleton (IKleisliTupled Pure))

-- Straightforward but not very usable

bprog
  ::
    Free
      (File `SumP` Bar `SumP` Foo)
      '( 'FileClosed, '( 'YesBar, 'NoFoo))
      '( 'FileClosed, '( 'NoBar, 'YesFoo))
      ()
bprog = do
  bsend LP (Open "/tmp/foo.txt")
  x <- bsend LP Read
  bsend (RP . RP) Foo
  bsend (RP . LP) Bar
  bsend LP (Write x)
  bsend LP Close

-- * Attempt 3

class Inject' f i o (fs :: j -> j -> * -> *) where
  type I f i o fs :: j
  type O f i o fs :: j
  inj' :: forall x. f i o x -> fs (I f i o fs) (O f i o fs) x

instance Inject' f i o f where
  type I f i o f = i
  type O f i o f = o
  inj' = id

-- Illegal polymorphic type: forall (s :: k1). '(il, s)

instance Inject' fl il ol (SumP fl fr) where
  type I fl il ol (SumP fl fr) = forall s. '(il, s)
  type O fl il ol (SumP fl fr) = forall s. '(ol, s)
  inj' = LP

instance (Inject' f i' o' fr) =>
         Inject' f i' o' (SumP fl fr) where
  type I f i' o' (SumP fl fr) = forall s. '(s, I f i' o' fr)
  type O f i' o' (SumP fl fr) = forall s. '(s, O f i' o' fr)
  inj' = RP . inj
```

So Attempt 1 destroys type inference. Attempt 2 has bad ergonomics for the user. Attempt 3 seems like the right approach, but I can't quite figure out how to make the associated type instances work out. What should this injection look like?

Answer (score 6):

I shall present first the currently standard way of handling open sums. I do it for plain non-indexed functors for the sake of simplicity and because the construction is the same for indexed ones. Then I'll introduce some enhancements enabled by GHC 8.

First, we define n-ary functor sums as a GADT indexed by a list of functors. This is more convenient and cleaner than using binary sums.

```
{-# language
  RebindableSyntax, TypeInType, TypeApplications,
  AllowAmbiguousTypes, GADTs, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables,
  UndecidableInstances, LambdaCase, EmptyCase, TypeOperators, ConstraintKinds,
  FlexibleContexts, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Kind

data NS :: [* -> *] -> * -> * where
  Here  :: f x -> NS (f ': fs) x
  There :: NS fs x -> NS (f ': fs) x

instance Functor (NS '[]) where
  fmap _ = \case {}

instance (Functor f, Functor (NS fs)) => Functor (NS (f ': fs)) where
  fmap f (Here fx)  = Here  (fmap f fx)
  fmap f (There ns) = There (fmap f ns)
```

Projecting and injecting can be either done

- Directly with a class, but this needs overlapping or incoherent instances.
- Indirectly, first computing the index of the element where we'd like to inject, then using the (natural number) index to define class instances without overlapping.

The latter solution is the preferable one, so let's see that:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family Find (x :: a) (xs :: [a]) :: Nat where
  Find x (x ': xs) = Z
  Find x (y ': xs) = S (Find x xs)

class Elem' (n :: Nat) (f :: * -> *) (fs :: [* -> *]) where
  inj' :: forall x. f x -> NS fs x
  prj' :: forall x. NS fs x -> Maybe (f x)

instance (gs ~ (f ': gs')) => Elem' Z f gs where
  inj'           = Here
  prj' (Here fx) = Just fx
  prj' _         = Nothing

instance (Elem' n f gs', (gs ~ (g ': gs'))) => Elem' (S n) f gs where
  inj'            = There . inj' @n
  prj' (Here _)   = Nothing
  prj' (There ns) = prj' @n ns

type Elem f fs = (Functor (NS fs), Elem' (Find f fs) f fs)  

inj :: forall fs f x. Elem f fs => f x -> NS fs x
inj = inj' @(Find f fs)

prj :: forall f x fs. Elem f fs => NS fs x -> Maybe (f x)
prj = prj' @(Find f fs)
```

Now in ghci:

```
> :t inj @[Maybe, []] (Just True)
inj @[Maybe, []] (Just True) :: NS '[Maybe, []] Bool
```

However, our `Find` type family is somewhat problematic because its reduction is often blocked by type variables. GHC disallows branching on inequality of type variables, because unification can possibly instantiate different variables to equal types later (and making premature decisions based on inequality can lead to loss of solutions).

For example:

```
> :kind! Find Maybe [Maybe, []]
Find Maybe [Maybe, []] :: Nat
= 'Z  -- this works
> :kind! forall (a :: *)(b :: *). Find (Either b) [Either a, Either b]
forall (a :: *)(b :: *). Find (Either b) [Either a, Either b] :: Nat
= Find (Either b) '[Either a, Either b] -- this doesn't
```

In the second example GHC doesn't commit to the inequality of `a` and `b` so it can't step over the first list element.

This historically caused rather annoying type inference deficiencies in Data Types a la Carte and extensible effects libraries. For example, even if we have just a single `State s` effect in a functor sum, writing `(x :: n) <- get` in a context where only `Num n` is known results in type inference failure, because GHC can't compute the index of the `State` effect when the state parameter is a type variable.

However, with GHC 8 we can write a significantly more powerful `Find` type family, which looks into type expressions to see if there's a unique possible position index. For example, if we're trying to find a `State s` effect, if there's only a single `State` in the effect list, we can safely return its position without looking at the `s` parameter, and subsequently GHC will be able to unify `s` with the other state parameter contained in the list.

First, we need a generic traversal of type expressions:

```
import Data.Type.Bool

data Entry = App | forall a. Con a

type family (xs :: [a]) ++ (ys :: [a]) :: [a] where
  '[]       ++ ys = ys
  (x ': xs) ++ ys = x ': (xs ++ ys)

type family Preord (x :: a) :: [Entry] where
  Preord (f x) = App ': (Preord f ++ Preord x)
  Preord x     = '[ Con x]
```

`Preord` converts an arbitrary type into a list of its sub-expressions in preorder. `App` denotes the places where type constructor application occurs. For example:

```
> :kind! Preord (Maybe Int)
Preord (Maybe Int) :: [Entry]
= '['App, 'Con Maybe, 'Con Int]
> :kind! Preord [Either String, Maybe]
Preord [Either String, Maybe] :: [Entry]
= '['App, 'App, 'Con (':), 'App, 'Con Either, 'App, 'Con [],
   'Con Char, 'App, 'App, 'Con (':), 'Con Maybe, 'Con '[]]
```

After this, writing the new `Find` is just a matter of functional programming. My implementation below converts the list of types into a list of index-traversal pairs, and successively filters out entries from the list by comparing the traversals of the list elements and the to-be-found element.

```
type family (x :: a) == (y :: b) :: Bool where
  x == x = True
  _ == _ = False

type family PreordList (xs :: [a]) (i :: Nat) :: [(Nat, [Entry])] where
  PreordList '[]       _ = '[]
  PreordList (a ': as) i = '(i, Preord a) ': PreordList as (S i)

type family Narrow (e :: Entry) (xs :: [(Nat, [Entry])]) :: [(Nat, [Entry])] where
  Narrow _ '[]                     = '[]
  Narrow e ('(i, e' ': es) ': ess) = If (e == e') '[ '(i, es)] '[] ++ Narrow e ess

type family Find_ (es :: [Entry]) (ess :: [(Nat, [Entry])]) :: Nat where
  Find_ _        '[ '(i, _)] = i
  Find_ (e ': es) ess        = Find_ es (Narrow e ess)

type Find x ys = Find_ (Preord x) (PreordList ys Z)
```

Now we have:

```
> :kind! forall (a :: *)(b :: *). Find (Either a) [Maybe, [], Either b]
forall (a :: *)(b :: *). Find (Either a) [Maybe, [], Either b] :: Nat
= 'S ('S 'Z)
```

This `Find` can be used in any code involving open sums, and it works for indexed and non-indexed types all the same.

[Here's](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/master/haskell/Eff/EffInference.hs) some example code with the kind of injection/projection presented above, for non-indexed extensible effects.

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with your `NS`. The trouble is that extending it to work with indexed functors is not obvious to me.

`data NS (fs :: [* -> *]) is os (a :: *)`

What should the kinds of `is` and `os` be (if we want to support indexed functors where each functor can be indexed by types of a different kind)? A type-level hlist? A list of open unions?

Comment: By the way, it's possible to give the `Functor (NS fs)` instance directly in terms of a claim that all the `fs` are functors: http://lpaste.net/5782847892658061312

Comment: Could you possibly explain how it helps to give a *traversal* of the type, rather than just a tree representing it or the type itself?

Comment: @JesseC OK, I understand now that you'd like to get coproducts of indexed functors that are indexed by the product of indices. That takes some extra work indeed. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @dfeuer Going further we can use `StandaloneDeriving` to avoid writing the instance — `deriving instance All Functor fs => Functor (NS fs)`

Comment: @AndrásKovács Sorry for the slightly OT question but I'm wondering about the usefulness of this when used for extensible effects. Wouldn't most functions have a type with a polymorphic effect list so that they can be combined? Does this trick help with inference when your type is something like `Elem (State s) effs => Eff effs ()` instead of `Eff [State s] ()`?

Comment: @LukaHorvat it solves all the type inference problems with extensible effects, in comparison to `mtl` (and also supports multiple effects of the same type and labelled effects). See [this](https://github.com/AndrasKovacs/misc-stuff/blob/master/haskell/Eff/EffInference.hs) for example. It's probably worth a writeup or a pull request. I haven't yet gotten around to promote it in any way.

Comment: @AndrásKovács I've tried this `f :: (Num s, Elem (State s) effs) => Eff effs ()` `f = do { put 5; modify (+1) }` and it doesn't infer. Your examples work because the `run` function forces the effects into a concrete list. I was hoping that what you showed somehow magically helps in these cases as well.

Comment: Kinds can be polymorphic (`NS :: [ĸ -> Type] -> (ĸ -> Type)` — and — `Elem' :: Nat -> (ĸ -> Type) -> [ĸ -> Type] -> Constraint`). `inj'`, `prj'` can be combined into a `Prism' (NS fs x) (f x)` and the `==` type family is available from `Data.Type.Equality`.

Comment: @LukaHorvat: delete the type annotation, then it works, with a more general type. A general GHC  bug/limitation prevents us from annotating that example correctly.

Comment: @Iceland_jack: `Data.Type.Equality` equality is kind homogeneous, so does not work in this case.

Comment: Yeah noticed that after I posted

Comment: @AndrásKovács Yeah, it does but only with AllowAmbiguousTypes enabled. Is this generally ok?

Comment: @LukaHorvat `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is OK and essential with `TypeApplications`. However, to be clear, I think that GHC type checking performance and error messages aren't nearly good enough to make this thing practical. I don't think extensible effects are particularly good in practice either.

Comment: @JesseC: [here's](http://lpaste.net/346426) some code with indexing in the way you'd like to have. It does involve lifted heterogeneous lists. Unfortunately GHC bugs prevented me from writing interpreters for effects. This seems to be beyond the scope of things that can be written with GHC while preserving our sanity.

Comment: Oh, now I understand, I think. You want to match on the outermost part of the outermost part, etc., first, and only narrow till you get down to one. I guess that's the Right Thing for certain uses, though surely not all.

Comment: @dfeuer the question is which traversal to precommit to, given that encountering any type variable on the way makes us stuck. Generally, outer type constructors are less polymorhpic. Preorder bfs and dfs seem the best, with bfs being probably better, but the problem with bfs is that it always gets stuck if there's a variable at the head of an application spine. Hence I chose preorder dfs. For realistic (extensible-effects etc.) use cases, we rarely get to the point where dfs versus bfs makes a difference.

Comment: @dfeuer ofc, ideal would be full access to term structure including variables, similarly to reflection in Agda and Coq.

Comment: @AndrásKovács, which tree are you talking about BFS in? The tree that strikes me as most natural is `data Ent where Ap :: a -> [Ent] -> Ent; Co :: a -> Ent`, which represents `f a b` as `Ap f [Co a, Co b]`. Is that the one you're talking about?

Comment: @dfeuer yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Aha, I got it to work! The key thing I took from András Kovács second attempt (linked in a comment) is the trick with leaving the instance head general and then refining with an equality constraint.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  RankNTypes, RebindableSyntax, TypeFamilies, TypeInType,
  TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}

module Example2 (res, prog') where

import Control.Monad.Indexed
import Data.TASequence.FastCatQueue
import Prelude hiding ((>>), (>>=))

-- * Indexed free machinery

(>>=)
  :: (IxMonad m)
  => m s1 s2 a -> (a -> m s2 s3 b) -> m s1 s3 b
(>>=) = (>>>=)
(>>)
  :: (IxApplicative m)
  => m s1 s2 a -> m s2 s3 b -> m s1 s3 b
f >> g = imap (const id) f `iap` g

type family Fst x where
  Fst '(a, b) = a
type family Snd x where
  Snd '(a, b) = b

newtype IKleisliTupled m ia ob = IKleisliTupled
  { runIKleisliTupled :: Snd ia -> m (Fst ia) (Fst ob) (Snd ob)
  }

tApp :: (TASequence s, IxMonad m) => s (IKleisliTupled m) x y -> (IKleisliTupled m) x y
tApp fs =
  case tviewl fs of
    TAEmptyL -> IKleisliTupled ireturn
    f :< fs' ->
      IKleisliTupled
        (\a -> runIKleisliTupled f a >>= runIKleisliTupled (tApp fs'))

data Free f s1 s2 a where
  Pure :: a -> Free f s s a
  Impure ::
    f s1 s2 a ->
      FastTCQueue (IKleisliTupled (Free f)) '(s2, a) '(s3, b) ->
        Free f s1 s3 b

instance IxFunctor (Free f) where
  imap f (Pure a) = Pure $ f a
  imap f (Impure a g) = Impure a (g |> IKleisliTupled (Pure . f))
instance IxPointed (Free f) where
  ireturn = Pure
instance IxApplicative (Free f) where
  iap (Pure f) (Pure a) = ireturn $ f a
  iap (Pure f) (Impure a g) = Impure a (g |> IKleisliTupled (Pure . f))
  iap (Impure a f) m = Impure a (f |> IKleisliTupled (`imap` m))
instance IxMonad (Free f) where
  ibind f (Pure a) = f a
  ibind f (Impure a g) = Impure a (g |> IKleisliTupled f)

-- * Example application

data FileStatus
  = FileOpen
  | FileClosed
data File i o a where
  Open :: FilePath -> File 'FileClosed 'FileOpen ()
  Close :: File 'FileOpen 'FileClosed ()
  Read :: File 'FileOpen 'FileOpen String
  Write :: String -> File 'FileOpen 'FileOpen ()

foldFile :: File i o a -> a
foldFile (Open _) = ()
foldFile Close = ()
foldFile Read = "demo"
foldFile (Write _) = ()

data MayFoo
  = YesFoo
  | NoFoo
data Foo i o a where
  Foo :: Foo 'NoFoo 'YesFoo ()

data MayBar
  = YesBar
  | NoBar
data Bar i o a where
  Bar :: Bar 'YesBar 'NoBar ()

-- * Coproduct of indexed functors

infixr 5 `SumP`
data SumP f1 f2 t1 t2 x where
  LP :: f1 sl1 sl2 x -> SumP f1 f2 '(sl1, sr) '(sl2, sr) x
  RP :: f2 sr1 sr2 x -> SumP f1 f2 '(sl, sr1) '(sl, sr2) x

newtype VoidFunctor is os a = VoidFunctor (VoidFunctor is os a)
absurd :: VoidFunctor is os a -> b
absurd a = a `seq` spin a where
   spin (VoidFunctor b) = spin b

extract :: Free VoidFunctor '() '() a -> a
extract (Pure a) = a
extract (Impure f _) = absurd f

runPure
  :: (forall j p b. f j p b -> b)
  -> Free (f `SumP` fs) '(i, is) '(o, os) a
  -> Free fs is os a
runPure _ (Pure a) = Pure a
runPure f (Impure (RP cmd) q) = Impure cmd (tsingleton k)
  where k = IKleisliTupled $ \a -> runPure f $ runIKleisliTupled (tApp q) a
runPure f (Impure (LP cmd) q) = runPure f $ runIKleisliTupled (tApp q) (f cmd)

-- * Injection

class Inject l b where
  inj :: forall a. l a -> b a

instance Inject (f i o) (f i o) where
  inj = id

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-}
  (is ~ '(il, s), os ~ '(ol, s)) =>
  Inject (fl il ol) (SumP fl fr is os) where
  inj = LP

instance (Inject (f i' o') (fr is' os'), is ~ '(s, is'), os ~ '(s, os')) =>
         Inject (f i' o') (SumP fl fr is os) where
  inj = RP . inj

send
  :: Inject (t i o) (f is os)
  => t i o b -> Free f is os b
send t = Impure (inj t) (tsingleton (IKleisliTupled Pure))

-- * In use

prog = do
  send (Open "/tmp/foo.txt")
  x <- send Read
  send Foo
  send (Write x)
  send Bar
  send Close
  ireturn x

prog' ::
  Free
    (File `SumP` Foo `SumP` Bar `SumP` VoidFunctor)
    '( 'FileClosed, '( 'NoFoo, '( 'YesBar, '())))
    '( 'FileClosed, '( 'YesFoo, '( 'NoBar, '())))
    String
prog' = prog

res :: String
res = extract . runPure (\Bar -> ()) . runPure (\Foo -> ()) . runPure foldFile $ prog
```

P.S. I'll see if I can move toward the nicer open union encoding or if I too will run into inscrutable GHC problems.

Comment: In the meantime I've found the issue with my code which was my fault rather than GHC's (just mixing up indices in constraints). Now everything works fine, [here's the code](http://lpaste.net/347242).

Comment: @AndrásKovács Ooh, interesting. I finally got around to looking at this again and I'm running into an inconvenience. If you don't want the union to be "concrete", which is important for compositionality, you end up having to do the first approach here:
http://lpaste.net/357141
It seems like you ought to be able to do just the second. Can you think of a way of encoding it so that the second is possible?

Comment: @AndrásKovács The other problem I encounter when trying to write `runFile`. I can get it to work, but only with the help of `unsafeCoerce`. Is there some way to avoid it? http://lpaste.net/357146

Comment: I'll look at it. You can read [this](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/st/index.html) if you haven't already, for hints; it's a library in Idris with a superset of our features (much more powerful, in fact).

Comment: I'm not very motivated though. We need proper proofs and/or reflection and proof search, which is absent or crap in Haskell. E. g. we need that `(Elem x (y : ys) ∧ (x /= y) => Elem x ys)`, or that `(forall ys. Elem x xs => Elem x (xs ++ ys))` and so on.

Comment: Yeah. I also came across http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/extensible/ParamEff1.hs which is relevant but doesn't happen to confront either of the two present issues.